Issue while Autowiring beans in SpringBoot
I am trying to create a project with Spring boot JDBC.
I have defined all the required classes with attributes.
But when I run the application, I am getting NullPointerException.
Below is the code:
Bean Configuration:

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceV2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("url")
                .username("username")
                .password("password")
                .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean("namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSourceV2());
    }
}


AbstractDAO class
public abstract class AbstractDAO {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2;
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedParameterJdbcTemplateV2() {
        return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2")
    public void setNamedParameterJdbcTemplateV2(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2 = namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2;
    }

}


DAOImplementation class

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:MultiSourceSQL.properties")
public class GuestInfoDAOV2Impl extends AbstractDAO implements GuestInfoDAOV2 {


    @Value("${guestInfoSQLV2}")
    private String guestInfoSQLV2;

    @Qualifier("guestInfoResultSetExtractorV2")
    @Autowired
    private ResultSetExtractor<GuestInfoV2DTO> guestInfoResultSetExtractorV2;

    @Override
    public GuestInfoV2DTO getGuestInfo(int beginIndex, int endIndex) throws DataAccessException {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(BEGININDEX, beginIndex);
        params.put(ENDINDEX, endIndex);
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2 = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplateV2();
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2.query(guestInfoSQLV2, params, guestInfoResultSetExtractorV2);
    }
}

When I am debugging the GuestInfoDAOV2Impl class, I am getting null for all the 3 properties(guestInfoSQLV2, guestInfoResultSetExtractorV2, namedParameterJdbcTemplateV2).
Additional Info:
have created another configuration class to inject bean
@Bean public GuestInfoDAOV2 getGuestInfoDAOV2() { 
return new GuestInfoDAOV2Impl(); } 

Also, I have created a TestClass with run method:
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("getGuestInfoDAOV2") 
GuestInfoDAOV2Impl guestInfoDAOV2; 
public void run() {
GuestInfoListV2DTO list = guestInfoDAOV2.getGuestInfo(100000000, 100010508); 
list.getGuestInfoDTOList().get(0); 
}

Calling the above class from main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NghpContentIndexingApplication.class, args);
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        testClass.run();
    }

Can someone please help with why the beans are not getting injected in the code.
Let me know if any more information is required.
SpringBoot version 3.3.0

how do you autowire/instantiate that GuestInfoDAOV2Impl class?

@Stultuske Added more information based on your inputs

Just a side note, I have added it in main class just to check if my code is working or not.

Got the issue.
Fixed it by Adding
ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(NghpContentIndexingApplication.class, args);
TestClass testClass = applicationContext.getBean(TestClass.class);
testClass.run();

Fixed the issue by adding applicationContext.getBean() method :
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        TestClass testClass = applicationContext.getBean(TestClass.class);
        testClass.run();

    }
}


Even if this causes your wanted behavior, this is not a fix. You should understand what’s wrong with your dependency injection and bean resolution. If you just want to run something after it was instantiated you should consider having a method annotated with “@PostConstruct”

@kSp this IS a fix. The problem was that Spring wasn't managing the instantiation of TestClass. Since it didn't, it also couldn't manage the Autowired fields in that class.

@Stultuske It’s not really a fix, more of a workaround nor is it the answer to the original question. The question was what’s wrong with the autowiring and the answer is simply “nothing” everything behaved exactly as it was expected.

@kSp no, it didn't. It behaved as coded, not as expected.

@Stultuske you can try to flip the words but at the end it’s still the same. It behaves completely as expected by the given code! To code you need to understand principles and one of that is for example what an instance is, how it behaves in the language that I’m using. Also you need to understand a framework if you want to use it. And for spring basics are DI, IoC…. Are needed to write good applications. this is completely behaving as expected by that code! And OP should understand why it’s a bad idea to manually inject a bean in the main class!

yes, that is what I said. But the point is, telling the OP that the code is running as is expected, is wrong, because it doesn't do what he expects it to do. It's running as is to be expected. I already pointed out that it's a DI issue in the first comment, before any answer. OP 'expected' it to work. It didn't. So, it did not work 'as expected'. The above resolved the issues with the framework, so yes, it is a fix.

The three variables that are null each represent different types: one is a value, another is an Autowired object, and the third is a method return. One possible reason for this could be that the package containing the class GuestInfoDAOV2Impl is not being scanned by the Application context.

In your Main Method you just instantiate TestClass yourself and call the run-Method. Spring will never inject a bean in this Class. This instance of the class is not spring managed.
If you want Spring to manage the dependencies from TestClass you need to make it any kind of bean by annotating it with ‘@Service’ or ‘@Component’ or add it to a Configuration File and annotate it with ‘@Bean’.
Or you could remove ‘@Autowired’ from the dependencies in TestClass and inject the fields yourself.
If you want it to do something after being instantiated you can annotate the run method with ‘@PostConstruct’.
As further explanation, in your answer you use the application context to resolve the wanted Bean. This is working because you already created the Bean with the Bean-Annotation and the instance you resolve from the Context is Spring Managed vs. before you just instantiated it yourself.
